# Wordpress tinymce editor height bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

The screenshot shows the issue: toolbar/content height.

[image]

tinymcse related code:

```
// wordpress plugin:

add_filter('admin_head', array($this, 'editor_tiny_mce'));
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', array($this, 'change_mce_options'));

function editor_tiny_mce()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('common');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-color');
    wp_print_scripts('editor');
    if (function_exists('add_thickbox'))
    {
        add_thickbox();
    }
    wp_print_scripts('media-upload');
    if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce'))
    {
        wp_tiny_mce();
    }
    wp_admin_css();
    wp_enqueue_script('utils');
    do_action("admin_print_styles-post-php");
    do_action('admin_print_styles');
}

function change_mce_options($init)
{
    $init['height'] = '480px'; // this not works
    return $init;
}

// html code

<?php
echo the_editor(stripslashes($pages_about_us_content), 'pages_about_us_content');
?>
```

I tried solve it with this code too:

```
$("iframe[id$='_ifr']").height(500); // this not works
```

because all tinymce frames ends with `_ifr` but no luck. This only seems occur when editor shows only one toolbar.

Please any advice is welcome.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653009/how-do-i-set-a-jquery-tooltip-from-a-database-on-server-side,

Comment: @elclanrs thanks but seems not related!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just add this code snippet inside your functions.php only for editor's toolbar size)

```
add_filter('admin_head', 'editor_tiny_mce');
function editor_tiny_mce(){
?>
    <style>
    table td.mceToolbar{
      height:100px !important;
    }
    </style>
<?php
}
```

[image]

The screenshot has been taken with height of 200px and you can also try `height:auto !important;`
**Note:** It's also possible to enqueue a css file with this code using 'wp_enqueue_style' function.

Comment: I think that I found a dirty solution, in any case I am building a plugin. Hack `functions.php` its much more dirty! THX :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that was for a plugin.

Comment: Well, I think you can use a css file and if you add the css file using wp_enqueue_style with that css rule then it could be solved too, just my opinion in case you think it's helpful when there is no solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. still no luck. I think that it is due that editors are hidden when page is loaded. I'll see it thanks!

Comment: in this case make the editor root html elemets visible before the editors get initialized (and hide them if necessary later)