# Can't adjust a Wordpress plugin's editor height

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin, [WpDocs](https://wpdocs.co/knowledge-base/docs/), that creates a custom post type using the [plugin's editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIwQL.png) but I can't seem to figure out how to adjust the height of the editor on init. The plugin uses the TinyMCE editor and I've found [information on how to add a filter to the main TinyMCE editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864318/wordpress-tinymce-editor-height-bug), but I don't know how to target [this editor here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRtlm.png). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

There are two parameters that you can use to change the size of the text editor generated with `wp_editor()`:

```php
$settings = array(
    'editor_height' => 425, // In pixels, takes precedence and has no default value
    'textarea_rows' => 20,  // Has no visible effect if editor_height is set, default is 20
);
```

Comment: Neither of these seem to work any longer.  Super frustrating.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation, but with a smart guess, I found this works:
'height' => 425   where 425 is the height in pixels.  Tested with WP 5.7.1